# RuntimeError at /contact_pdf unexpected exception in unicode2T1 @ src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c:634 caused by bad argument type for built-in

Tags: django-models, django-views, reportlab

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I get the error in the subject, what did I do wrong?
In other app is working...

**views.py:**

```
[def contact_pdf(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
    textob = c.beginText()
    textob.setTextOrigin(inch, inch)
    textob.setFont("Helvetica", 14)
    contact = Contact.objects.all()
    lines = \[\]
    for contact in contact:
        lines.append(contact.name)
        lines.append(contact.city)
        lines.append(contact.county)
        lines.append(contact.street_name)
        lines.append(contact.street_number)
        lines.append(contact.floor)
        lines.append(contact.apartment_number)
        lines.append(contact.building_info)
        lines.append(contact.zip_code)
        lines.append(contact.phone)
        lines.append(contact.web)
        lines.append(contact.email_address)
        lines.append('====================================')
    for line in lines:
        textob.textLine(line)
    c.drawText(textob)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='contact.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert all the appending data into string format like:

```
lines.append(str(contact.name)
```